# bash + break syntax + exit from loop by break n

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

we build the following loop in bash script

```
until [[ $completed == true ]]
do
if .....
   then
   echo "procedure ended"
   break # break the for looop
else
   .
   .
fi
.
.
done
```

we want to exit from the loop , when procedure ended ( see `echo "procedure ended"` )

we are not sure if we need to set `break` or `break 1` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[POSIX specification of `break [n]`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#break) explicitly says [emphasis mine]:

> If `n` is specified, the `break` utility shall exit from the `n`th enclosing `for`, `while`, or `until` loop. **If `n` is not specified, `break` shall behave as if `n` was specified as `1`.** Execution shall continue with the command immediately following the exited loop. The value of `n` is a positive decimal integer. If `n` is greater than the number of enclosing loops, the outermost enclosing loop shall be exited. If there is no enclosing loop, the behavior is unspecified.

Bash conforms to this specification. So the answer is: it doesn't matter, `break` and `break 1` are equivalent.